# QLIKVIEW Month and Year displayed wrong

Tags: qlikview

I have problem with dates. When I convert the dates from daily basis to monthly and yearly, the tables start with 0 as the first value.

For example, see table below. I loaded the data into Qlikview from a MySQL database and I'm pretty sure I've loaded the data properly to Qlikview. Any help would be appreciated.

```
year month
0     0
2008  1
2009  2
2010  3
      4
      5
      6 
      7
      8  
      9
      10 
      11 
      12
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! Please take some minutes for the http://stackoverflow.com/tour. After that please re-format your question. Especially the data. And if you add your load script, the community may be can solve your problem.

Comment: can you share your script or better QVW sample? it can be many issues - data type conversion between mysql and QV, formatting issue on your machine and format string in QV. You have control of doing the values interpretation yourself - check formatting and interpretation functions in QV i.e. how date() function is different from date#()

Answer (score 1):

Set up a chart object of type straight table, and add the your dimensions there and expression to it. You will most likely see that missing values are going to get assigned zero to it.

So the answer is, most likely that your data is sometimes missing a date and therefore getting the zero. Look at your table viewer (ctrl-t) and make sure that your table links are correct and eventually coalesce your dates to a default so you won't get null converted to zero.

If this is not the issue, please post your load script.